# Convert object to string MSSQL PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, object

I am connecting to a MSSQL database with PHP using Microsoft ODBC 11 Driver. I am quering the database successfully and receiving the data i want but having problems displaying it. The array I am fetching from the database has some objects which are dates and I do not know how to display them correctly in a table. Now I am receiving a Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

And here is the code. The commented code in the second `foreach` is where I am trying to convert the object into string and display only the date without the other properties of the object.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    require_once('sqlcon.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.operations WHERE OperType=4";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    $tableHeaderWritten = false;

    echo "<table>";
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        if(!$tableHeaderWritten) {
                echo "<tr>";        
                foreach ($row as $columns => $rows) {
                    //var_dump($row);
                echo "<th>$columns</th>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                $tableHeaderWritten = true;
        }

        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row  as $columns => $rows) {
                if(is_object($rows)) {
                    //$results = array();
                    //$results = $rows->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    //foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
                        //var_dump($value);
                        //echo "<th>$value</th>";
                    }

                }

                echo "<th>$rows</th>";
                }

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

And this is the dumped array I am fetching:

```
 `array (size=23)
  'ID' => int 3756022
  'OperType' => int 4
  'Acct' => int 1
  'GoodID' => int 3
  'PartnerID' => int 1
  'ObjectID' => int 4
  'OperatorID' => int 1
  'Qtty' => float 0
  'Sign' => int 1
  'PriceIn' => float 0
  'PriceOut' => float 1.98
  'VATIn' => float 0
  'VATOut' => float 0
  'Discount' => float 0
  'CurrencyID' => int 1
  'CurrencyRate' => float 1
  'Date' => 
    object(DateTime)[1]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-25 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
  'Lot' => string ' ' (length=1)
  'LotID' => int 1
  'Note' => string 'Изтриване на период към 25.05.2015' (length=54)
  'SrcDocID' => int 1
  'UserID' => int 1
  'UserRealTime' => 
     object(DateTime)[2]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-26 18:12:53' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)`
```

Comment: Should your `<table> while ( ...)...` loop look something like: [Pastebin: 31892252/convert-object-to-string-mssql-php](http://pastebin.com/28y6U3gu) ? Untested.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thank you very much. That is exactly what I needed. Do you know a usefull resource where I can read more about objects in php. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ryan Vincent I have a solution to my question. I am posting only the second `foreach` where are the changes.

```
foreach ($row as $columns => $rows) {
                if($rows instanceof \DateTime) {
                    echo "<td>" , $rows->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') , "</td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<td>$rows</td>";
                }           
        }
```